# How do you reject a migration?

Tags: support, migration

Further to Michael's recent question and since I couldn't quickly find information on rejecting migrations from SO^H^H other sites...

How do you reject a migration and what happens when you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [question that is migrated to another site is rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982) by that site if:

- it gets deleted
- it's closed as Not Constructive, NARQ, Too Localized, or generic Off-Topic

To reject a question that's been migrated here, you should vote to close for one of the reasons listed above.

When a question is rejected:

- it's unlocked (but not reopened) on the source site
- any answers that were deleted as part of the migration are undeleted on the source site
- all migrated answers are deleted on the destination site
- the migrated question and any answers received on the destination site are locked on the destination site

I can't find a definitive reference, but there are a few mentions of rejected migrations being deleted on the site they had been migrated to.  (After 30 days?)

Comment: That covers what happens during and after a migration but you completely failed to answer the main part of the question - "How do you reject a migration?"

Comment: ?? The first sentence and the two bullet points cover that.  You reject a migrated question by closing it for one of those reasons.  If it gets closed as a duplicate, e.g. that's not a rejection.

Comment: "is considered to be rejected" isn't the same as "how do I reject". I was attracted to the question in the hope that I might somehow be able to reject all that crap that comes over from SO. I didn't think it was possible but nevertheless the question title gave me hope. Extremely misleading.

Comment: Ok, I took out "considered to be" and clarified that you have to vote to help reject a question.

Comment: That's better, thanks.